# Creating Components And Setting It's Location

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, components

I'm developing a finance management WPF application for personal expenses control. There's a tab in my app called "Records", and it is suposed to show all the records of previously bought products. I have this DAO method to give me back all of the records.

```
 public List<TOProduct> LoadRecords(int id)
    {
        List<TOProduct> i = new List<TOProduct>();

    try
        {


            string sql = "select * from tbl_records where user_id = " + id + " and product_status = true";

            con = ConnectionFactory.Connection();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader dtreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (dtreader.Read())//If there's any data.
                {
                    TOProduct x = new TOProduct();

                    x.Id = dtreader.GetInt16("product_id");
                    x.Link = dtreader.GetString("product_link");
                    x.Name = dtreader.GetString("product_name");
                    x.Type = dtreader.GetString("product_type");
                    x.Price = dtreader.GetDouble("product_price");
                    x.Store = dtreader.GetString("product_store");
                    x.BuyingDate = dtreader.GetDateTime("product_buyingDate").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); ;

                    i.Add(x);

                }

                con.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return i;
    }
```

Which works just fine. Now, on my view I wanna create a panel that contains three labels: the Product Name label, the Product Price label and the Product Buying Date label. Problem is, I want to create one panel with this three labels to each registration returned from my method. Also, i'd need a scroll bar, since the user can have 1 or 1000 records, which in case woudn't fit to the screen. And these panels would have to be arrenged as a list. I know I can create some kind of `for(int i = 0; int i < number_of_records; i++)`. The problem is the creation of the components and it's locations on the screen.

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to create these components and set their locations on screen as i want? How? If there's no answer I'll probably just create a `DataGrid` and fill it with my `LoadRecords`return objects, but it'd be really great to have these components. Thanks in advence.

**EDIT:** Here's the image of what I want to do: [image]

This is the design I used for a "quick" menu that shows your 3 most recent purchases. But they are static, I just "feed" them with the information. I want to do a larger scale of this, to create each component dynamically and set it's location on screen, as said before.

Comment: But the solution to your problem is to use DataGrid/ GridView . Why you want to create a new componet . Also you can use a listControl as well and have 3 properties you can change the template for that of listbox

Comment: Never used listControl before. Could it be used the way I described? I'm not using DataGrid more for stetic reasons. I will use if everything else fails.

Comment: Are you using winform or web app?

Comment: Then why not to use Grid for that . What purpose was not served my datagrid  from your requirement ?

Comment: It's a design problem. I'll upload the image in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133445/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-pelicer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can activate this with ListView control. You need to set styles and UI formating but this will be best. It provides scrolling as well.

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.ListView_control.ListViewItemTemplateSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ListViewItemTemplateSample" Height="150" Width="350">
<Grid>
            <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvProducts">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel>

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=", " />

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text=")" />
                                    </WrapPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You can also use ListBox. as you have single column. ListView is used in different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can create  custom User Controls. [For Visual Studio 2015] Go To

- Visual C# => Windows => Classic Desktop and select WPF User Control
  Library.
- Add the controls that you would like to have in your custom control. I have added a textbox and a button.

Create properties that will be accessible after creation of the controls. To access events of any component, declare the event and add the event handler to the event in the constructor.

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public string SearchTextBoxText
        {
            get { return SearchTextBox.Text; }
            set { SearchTextBox.Text = value; }
        }

```
    public object SearchButtonContent
    {
        get { return SearchButton.Content; }
        set { SearchButton.Content = value; }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler SearchButton_Clicked;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     SearchButton_Clicked += SearchButton_Click;
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchButton_Clicked != null)
        {
            SearchButton_Clicked(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now build the solution.
PS: The UserControl project must be in the same Solution as your application project.
Now add a reference to this project in your application and you can use this custom control